# Localized string from resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-localization

I would like to add localized strings in my view.

**Resources/Views.Account.Login.en-US.resx**

[image]

**Views/Account/Login.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization    
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<div>
    @System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name                   
    @System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name
    @Localizer["Key"]
</div>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

    var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US")
        },
        SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US")
        },
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US")
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
}
```

**The generated HTML**

```
en-US
en-US
Key
```

**The expected HTML**

```
en-US
en-US
Hello
```

Have I forgotten a step?

**EDIT**

If the resources is named `Resources/Views.Account.Login.resx` is work correctly. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to inject `IStringLocalizer`

use `@inject IStringLocalizer<Your resources class name> _localizer;` in _ViewImports.cshtml

Comment: I am using `IStringLocalizer` everywhere. 
try to change `IViewLocalizer` with `IStringLocalizer`

Answer (score 0):

I have this code in `ConfigureServices`

```
var georgianCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ka-GE");
var englishCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var russianCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");

var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    georgianCultureInfo,
    englishCultureInfo,
    russianCultureInfo
};

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(georgianCultureInfo);
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
```

And this in `Configure`

```
var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you store the key value pair in Viewbag and use $.parse.JSON in jquery & loop through it & get the required values

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**

If the resources is named Resources/Views.Account.Login.resx is work correctly. Why ?

**Answer:**

last part `en-US` is for localization, if you omit it, that resource file will be chosen as default. `localizer` is checking `CurrentCulture` and then tries to find resource file with same ending part in name. if it couldn't find file, it will take default resource file.

Also try to remove parameter from `services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");` and left `services.AddLocalization();`